# cognos report studio drop down list to skip to other prompt page

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, textbox, cognos-10

I would like to use drop down list to choose different kind of time format to filter my report. For now, I use text box prompt and conditional variable help me to jump from DateFormat1, DateFormat2, DateFormat3. Though it work out well now, I need to use drop down list to finish this front page.
I would like to use HTML and JS to achieve it.
This is a drop down and textbox script I write.

```
<script language="javascript">
function ChooseContact(data) {

document.getElementById ("friendName").value = data.value;

}
</script> 

<select onchange="ChooseContact(this)">
<option value="0">Choose Time Format</option>
<option value="1">Billing Cycle</option>
<option value="2">Invoice Date</option>
<option value="3">Shipment Date</option>
<option value="4">Rating Date</option>
</select>
<input id="friendName">
```

But how to input my list number into text box prompt? Thanks!

Comment: I think I can help you but I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish. Can you clarify? Are you using your own prompts instead of the Cognos provided ones? What version of Cognos are you using?

Comment: i want to use drop down box to choose one of the time format in the first prompt page. E.g. I want to use Shipment Date to filter and present my other data( total weight, total shipments...). So I choose Shipment Date in the first page and press next. It will directly jump to the prompt page only have shipment date "date prompt". And other data will filtered by the time period I chosen. Now, I try to write HTML rather than use Cognos's prompt. Can I achieve my goal by using Cognos's prompt or I need to write HTML and JS script. I used Cognos 10.2. Thank you. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Why don't you use a Cognos value prompt, make it a drop-down type and pass in the value that way?

Comment: Originally, I regard that value prompt have to link with one query. After I read a article, I found the method you mention. Thanks a lot.